# Run Node.js forked processes in Docker containers

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, production-environment, docker, forever

I'm considering using [Docker](https://www.docker.io/) and thus trying to find as much information possible about it's integration with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) applications.

In production, my applications run the Node.js [`cluster`](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) module to `fork()` new processes and the [`domain`](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) module to catch errors, handle them and then `fork()` fresh processes.

[(Official example: "Warning: Don't Ignore Errors!")](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors)

My question is the following :

- How would I be able to put every new `fork()`'ed process inside a Docker container ?
- If it's not possible, are there any alternatives with which I could get error catching / handling features from, like [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [`forever`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) that would be compatible with docker ?

Any other resources about Docker good practices for Node.js applications are welcome too !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Processes forked by `cluster` module are in the same multi-core system. Processes in different containers belong to different virtual machines. So I don't think you can put processes forked by `cluster` module to different containers. Just run `pm2 start yourapp.js` in every container.